# showing different data based on selected segment control in monotouch

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios

I have an iPhone app I am building with MonoTouch (C#). My current view has a segmented control with three options. Depending on which segment is chosen, I want to display data related to the segment. The data will most likely require scrolling. My question is, what control(s) should I use to accomplish this? Do I use three ScrollView controls? If so, how do I show/hide each control based on the selected segment?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across a situation like this. In short, I did it with a single `UITableView` and `UITableSource`. When the user selects one segment, the appropriate data source is replaced with the one that corresponds to that specific segment and the table is reloaded (tableView.ReloadData() in most occasions).

It might get a bit complex, if for example "Segment A" contains text-only rows and "Segment B" contains text + image rows. In this case, you will need a bit more logic in the UITableSource's GetCell method to determine what cell will be displayed based on the type of data.

To minimize complexity, I have created a custom interface and generic class that inherits it:

```
interface ITableRow
{

    string RowTitle { get; set; }
    string RowSubTitle { get; set; }

}


class TableRow<T> : ITableRow
{

    public TableRow(string rowTitle, string rowSubtitle, T dataObject)
    {
        // fill the properties with values here
    }

    public string RowTitle { get; set; }
    public string RowSubTitle { get; set; }
    public T DataObject { get; set; }
}
```

My data source is always a `List<ITableRow>` (or a `Dictionary<TSome, ITableRow>` in some cases), so the `UITableSource.GetCell` implementation "knows" what to assign to each cell every time.

You could also extend it (I have) by adding the following constructor:

```
public TableRow(Func<string, T> rowTitleFunc, Func<string, T> rowSubtitleFunc, T dataObject) 
: this(rowTitleFunc(dataObject), rowSubtitleFunc(dataObject), dataObject) {}
```

This way you can display different data in each row based on each row's "dataObject".

PS (off topic): Don't you just love C# on iOS?